# Regarding conversion of units

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question regarding a conversion of units in an equation involving a power law, where:

$K = a \cdot (B^y)$

In the above equation, it is generated using a regression procedure where the units of K is $m^3$ and B is $m^2$. Both a and y are constants.

My question is, say if I wish to convert K to the units of $km^3$. What should be the corresponding changes in the units and values of B, as well as the values of a and y?

Thanks guys

Regards
Corse

Comment: Use dimensional analysis to find the dimensions of $a$ and $y$.  In your case $K$ -> $L^3$ and $B$ -> $L^2$.  Therefore you have $a L^{2y} = L^3$, i.e., $a = L^{3 - 2y}$.  If $y$ is dimensionless, the units of $a$ are directly given by the equation for $a$. The next step is to plug in $L = 1$ if units are meters and $L = 0.001$ if units are km to get the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an exponent, $y$ must be dimensionless, so it doesn't change. $B$ has dimensions of length$\ ^2$ and $K$ dimensions of length$\ ^3$, so $a$ has dimensions of length$\ ^{3-2y}$. If you change to km, the numeric values of $K$ will be divided by $1000^3$, of $B$ will be divided by $1000^2$ and $a$ will be ???

Comment: so a has to be divided by 1000^3

Comment: Not at all.  What were the units on $a$?

Comment: Hmm, im slightly confused now.  if I have K originally in m^3 and B originally in m^2, and I would like to change K to km^3 and B to km^2, do I not divide by 1000^3?

Comment: See the correction, please.  If $B$ is $m^2$, then $B^y$ is $m^{2y}$.  You divide $K$ by $1000^3$ and $B$ by $1000^{2y}$.  That means you divide $a$ by $1000^{3-2y}$.

Comment: oh i see, am i correct to say that, after dividing K by 1000^3, B by 1000^2y and a by 1000^(3-2y),the units of K will become KM^3,the units of B becomes KM^2? just an additional question, if original units are in KM and i wish to convert them into M, do i divide K by 0.001^3?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The additional question, too.  Of course, dividing by $0.001^3$ is the same as multiplying by $1000^3$  One way to see this is to think of multiplying  or dividing by $1$ in the form $\frac {1000 m}{1 km}$.  You need one power of this for each power of the length unit in question.

Comment: ah that's great. by the way, the exponent is unaffected whatsoever right?

Comment: Yes, the exponent needs to be unitless, so conversions will not matter.  We have no definition of raising thing to powers that have units.

Comment: got it, thank you for much of your time Ross!